# using kbpgp • how do I specify which key-pair to encrypt_with when calling kbpgp.box(params,cb)

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

```
var params = {
  msg:         "If you see me, I am working.",
  encrypt_for: bob,
  sign_with: alice
};

// where bob and alice are KeyManager objects with public and unlocked private keys

kbpgp.box(params, function(err, result_string, result_buffer) {
  console.log('\nencrypted message\n===========')
  console.log(result_string)
})
```

In this snippet I can specify which keypair I am using to sign.

How do I specify which KeyManager object I want to encrypt the message with, but not sign?

Is there an `encrypt_with` option I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `encrypt_for` parameter, which it expects to be a keymanager wrapping the recipient's public key.

The correct comment above the `kbpgp.box()` call would be:

`// where bob and alice are KeyManager objects with public and unlocked private keys, respectively`

In order to sign, you need an unlocked private key. But in order to encrypt, you simply need a public key.